# Как перебрать список и узнать порядковый номер определённого элемента?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Есть элемент select, в котором есть option с value.
Как мне узнать порядковый номер option с value, скажем 1111 на jquery?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант набросал по-быстрому на свой вкус. Скрипт зависит от того, как вы хотите передавать значение для поиска порядкового номера.

В моём варианте нужно ввести `value` в поле и нажать на кнопку для вывода порядкового номера, обработку несуществующих значение не делал.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calculate').click(function() {
    var valueCurrent = $('#valueCurrent').val();
    $('#optionCurrent').text($('select option[value=' + valueCurrent +']').index() + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="1111">1111</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<input type="text" id="valueCurrent" placeholder="Введите значение" />
<button id="calculate">Узнать порядковый номер</button>
<hr />
<div>Порядковый номер элемента: <span id="optionCurrent">0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Код будет примерно такой:

```
$("select option[value=1111]").index();
```